# How to read and write a log file (catalina.out) which has 10gb data using Spring batch and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Am Working on Log Monitoring task in Java. I need to read 10 gb log file using Spring Batch and trigger a mail with output file. Can any please help in this as am new to Spring batch.

Comment: Did you try anything? Research anything? Get stuck at a particular part?

Comment: you can googling with keyword 'spring batch flatfileitemreader example'.